# Wrong max-height when parent element has padding

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, chromium

In the example bellow, there is not used 100% of height from max-height (container's padding is subtracted).
It appears in Chrome and Safari, but not in Firefox.
Is it some chrome/webkit bug?

If you set instead of max-height height to 100%, the red frame will dissappear

The red frame is caused by padding of container element

```css
.containerWrapper {
  height: 400px;
}
.container {
  padding: 10px;
  background: yellow;
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
}
.dialog {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: red;
  height: 500px;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.dialogContent {
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="dialog">
    <p class="dialogContent">
      Dialog content
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here if also fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/8cykht4b/12/

Comment: We want to have dialog, with dynamic size, but not bigger, than the wrapper.
Then use overflow: auto; to be able to scroll content of dialog.
This I removed from css for clarity.

Comment: the maximum available height to child elements will be minus the padding, that is how it should work.  If you just want your absolute element to take up the whole height, use bottom 0 instead of height

Comment: I would probably agree on that, but what concerns me is that height is working different way then max-height when they are set to 100%
And also it works different in different browsers.

Comment: height + padding are added unless you reset box-sizing https://jsfiddle.net/vhs0xnaf/  -/- https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/ -/- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: But as you can see, it does nothing to the result. I was playing with box-sizing also.
So I removed it from fiddle to have there least properties set.